# Parsing Json after reading file with fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous, fs

I'm trying to establish communication between two node.js scripts.
The first one does a get request and write the response in a file.
The second watch the file after changes, then he read it, and prompt the result.

The first (get then write)

```
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var fs = require('fs');

//Some needed variables

streamInterval = setInterval(function() {
      request.get(addr, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        parseString(body,{ explicitArray : false, ignoreAttrs : true }, function (err, result) {
            var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(result);
            var result = JSON.parse(jsonResult);

            fs.writeFile(outputDeparts, JSON.stringify(result, null, 4), function(err) {
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
            }); 

        });
      }else{
        console.log("An error occured : " + response.statusCode);
      }
    }).auth(LOGIN,PASS,true);
  }, 30000);
```

The second (watch after changes, read and prompt)

```
var fs = require('fs');

//Some needed variables


fs.watch(outputDeparts, (eventType, filename) => {
  console.log(`event type is: ${eventType}`);
  if (filename) {
    console.log(`filename provided: ${filename}`);
    fs.readFile(outputDeparts, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err){
        throw err;
      }else{
        console.log('start parsing');
        console.log(data);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        var departs = result["passages"]["train"];
        console.log(`next train [${departs[0]["num"]}] at : ${departs[0]["date"]}`);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
  }
});
```

The first time the file is changed everything is ok ! But after 30 second, at the second change I get the following error :

```
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /Users/adobe/Documents/workspace/playWithNode/watchFile.js:17:23
    at tryToString (fs.js:414:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:401:12)
```

I thought it was a problem with reading/writting a file asynchronously but didn't manage to find a fix...
Is everyone able to help me or having clues ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..it isn't encouraged to access the file system asynchronously because, while accessing, the target file can be modified by something in the App Life Cycle.

I suggest you to use `fs.readFileSync` and to wrap the `JSON.parse` in a try-catch

```js
var fs = require('fs');

function onNextTrain(data) { 
  console.log("onNextTrain", data);
  
  return data;
}

fs.watch(outputDeparts, (eventType, filename) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!filename) {
      return reject("FILE NAME NOT PROVIDED");
    }
    
    let 
      data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'),
      result
    ;
    
    try {
      result = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch(error) {
      result = data;
    }
    
    return resolve(result);
  })
    .then(onNextTrain)
    .catch(err => console.log("error", err))
  ;
});
```

Comment: Just update it with resolve(result) and not data! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try change code in second file to

```
var result; 
try {
    result = JSON.parse(data);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err, data);
}
```

because `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` it's JSON.parse error.

In first file I see potential problem in
`fs.writeFile(outputDeparts, data, function(err) { ...`
Callback function must provide ordered write, but your code - only logged error.

Node.js docs

> Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, `fs.createWriteStream` is strongly recommended.